# What are $$Thunk@ entries in the Visual Studio Performance Profiler output?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, profiling, thunk

I've used the Visual Studio 2015 performance profiler (Alt+F2) on my code - a release build x64 EXE, a GUI program using SDL. Looking at the initial profiler report, the list has a number of `$$Thunk@` entries.

```
$$Thunk@00004c41
$$Thunk@000050ab
$$Thunk@00002590
$$Thunk@00001654
```

All supposedly come from my program's module, but when I right click the `View Source` option is greyed out.

The code of their supposed callers contain no calls to them.

These symbols don't appear when I run the EXE or PDB through `strings -a`, they don't appear in the disassembly produced by `dumpbin /disasm`, and I can't visit them in the disassembly window in the debugger.

What do these entries refer to?